# Bash regex is not working for git branch names

Tags: regex, bash, sh

I have the following script:

```
valid_branch_regex="^(feature|bugfix|improvement|library|prerelease|release|hotfix)\/(?=[A-Z]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}).{3,9}\/[a-z0-9._-]+$"
local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
[[ $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]] && echo matched
```

Why it doesn't print "matched" if the `local_branch` is `feature/III-111/some-name` ?

Comment: Please show an example output for your `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` command.

Comment: @lurker feature/III-111/some-name

Comment: @VladislavPokosenko Your regex matches if you remove `?=` and `.{3,9}`. You don't have to escape both `/`, but you should double quote your `$local_branch` variable (left side of the test).

Comment: So you want to implement a check that the `III-111` part can only be of 3 to 9 chars long and match the `[A-Z]+-[0-9]+` pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes. And `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` min lengths is 1.

Answer (score 4):

you're trying to use a positive lookahead (`?=`). This is not supported in bash. Bash supports only extended regexps ( ERE ). Lookaheads were introduced as a part of PCRE ( Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) , which Bash does not support natively.

You can check the exit status by adding `echo $?` to the end of your code, which will output 2 indicating that the regex in syntactically incorrect.

Reference : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: also adding `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` helps greatly debugging Regexes in Bash.